# How I can code a input method on Windows 8?

Tags: windows

Like is title, I want to write a module program to add a input method into language preferences on Windows 8. I need to write a input method in my language.

https://fbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/561154_233448566780818_2089636107_n.jpg

Help me!

Answer (score 2):

see your question seems unclear on imcomplete. Let me guess, if you want the user to enter the  URL format in your textbox . 
Lets have this example XAML

```
<textbox x: Name="textBox1" **InputScope="URL"** </textbox>
```

this might help you

Comment: I think OP wants to add input method for his native language which is not provided with the OS or by Microsoft.